# Why is SELECT without columns valid

Tags: postgresql

I accidently wrote a query like `select from my_table;` and surprisingly it is valid statement. Even more interesting to me is that even `SELECT;` is a valid query in PostgreSQL. You can try to write a lot funny queries with this:

```
select union all select;
with t as (select) select;
select from (select) a, (select) b;
select where exists (select);
create table a (b int); with t as (select) insert into a (select from t);
```

Is this a consequence of some definition SQL standard, or there is some use case for it, or it is just funny behavior that no one cared to programatically restrict?

Comment: I think your question would be even more powerful if you included some of the output you get from this funky looking queries.

Comment: why not?.. you want to select no columns and you select it... In oracle you use `select 'TEXT FROM NO COLUMN' from dummy` in postgres you just select straight away. and if you want to select not only no column, but and no value, what is there to be restricted?..

Comment: @VaoTsun: `select 'TEXT FROM NO COLUMN' from dummy` still selects **one** column. Tomas' example uses `select` or `select from t` which has **no** column at all.

Comment: In which version of PostgreSQL? In 9.3 and 9.4 `select from tab` gives: `syntax error at or near "from"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Right from the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#id-1.9.3.171.10.4)

> The list of output expressions after `SELECT` can be empty, producing a zero-column result table. This is not valid syntax according to the SQL standard. PostgreSQL allows it to be consistent with allowing zero-column tables. However, an empty list is not allowed when `DISTINCT` is used.

The possibility of "zero-column" tables is a side effect of the table inheritance if I'm not mistaken. There were discussions over this on the Postgres mailing lists (but I can't find them right now)