# How to use SELECT in PostgreSQL script without displaying output?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL script that sets up a database. One of the operations is creating a PostGIS geometry column:

```
...
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('table', 'column', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
...
```

However, this results in the following output:

```
               addgeometrycolumn                
------------------------------------------------
 public.table.column SRID:4326 TYPE:POINT DIMS:2
```

This clutters the output of the rest of the operations I'm doing. How can I supress this output?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function in FROM clause and add WHERE with a false condition, e.g.:

```
select res
from AddGeometryColumn('table', 'column', 4326, 'POINT', 2) res
where res isnull;
```

The function will be executed, the query returning no rows.

You can also try an [anonymous code block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
do $$ begin 
perform AddGeometryColumn('table', 'column', 4326, 'POINT', 2); 
end $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

In **PostgreSQL 9.4** and above, you can simply do the following.

```
SELECT 
WHERE EXISTS (AddGeometryColumn('table', 'column', 4326, 'POINT', 2));
```

Interestingly, the manual [says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#AEN84181) that `SELECT` without an output column is perfectly [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217629/why-is-select-without-columns-valid)!